# Image with 100vh but maintain aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an image which I would like to always be `100vw` & `100vh` no matter the screen resolution or view port. However I would like to keep some sort of aspect ratio to avoid stretching and skewing of the image.

This is what I have come up with so far which works lovely with the aspect ration but isn't `100vh` at all times. Can I make it so the image tag overflows negatively outside of the view port to maintain the image quality and keep the height `100vh`.

```
<div class="hero-img">
    <div class="hero-wrapper">
        <div class="hero-imgs"></div>
        <img src="myimg.png" alt="my hero img" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Styles

```
.hero-img{
    display:table;
    height:100vh;
    .hero-wrapper{
         display:table-row;
        .hero-imgs{
            display:table-cell;
          vertical-align:middle;
          text-align:center;
        }
        img{
        display:inline-block;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the `img` rule with `height: 100%;`

```css
.hero-img {
  display: table;
  height: 100vh;
}
.hero-img .hero-wrapper {
  display: table-row;
}
.hero-img .hero-wrapper .hero-imgs {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero-img .hero-wrapper img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-img">
  <div class="hero-wrapper">
    <div class="hero-imgs"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x600" alt="my hero img" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Update based on a comment, with an image with the opposite ratio

```css
.hero-img {
  display: table;
  height: 100vh;
}
.hero-img .hero-wrapper {
  display: table-row;
}
.hero-img .hero-wrapper .hero-imgs {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero-img .hero-wrapper img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-img">
  <div class="hero-wrapper">
    <div class="hero-imgs"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="my hero img" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi this works as a height rule however when the browser is scaled down to the viewport of a mobile device the image because squashed. Is there a way to pull the image out to a width of 150% for example to remove the stretching?

Comment: @user1910046 Updated with a 2:nd sample, where image is wider. This does not become squashed, so there must be some other CSS that kicks in stopping it from grow beyond the viewport